# How to get rid of black background in Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph like this.

[image]

the code I wrote for this is below:

```
 header=list(outcome)
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Terminated')
    green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Completed Positive')
    blue_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Completed Negative')
    plt.legend(handles=[red_patch,green_patch,blue_patch],fontsize=23)
    plt.title('MDS by Phase '+phase,fontsize=23)
    for x, y, w, name in zip(pos[:, 0], pos[:,1], pos[:, 2], header):
        if(name=='Completed Negative'):
            color='blue'
        elif(name=='Completed Positive'):
            color='green'
        else:
            color='red'
        ax.scatter(x, y, w,s=65,c=color)

    #fig.savefig('mds_ic_'+phase+'.png')
    fig.savefig('mds_obj_auto_'+phase+'.png')
```

I don't want the black background as when pasting the graph on a slide it is taking too much space but appears small since the remaining space is white which is not part of the graph. The black portion doesn't gel with the white background

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following lines:

```
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')

ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
```

One to remove the background from around the figure, one to change the axis colour, and the last three to change each axis's pane colour.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to make the inside also white. The background has become white but the axes and inside space is still grey

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to test your code, so this would be a guess `ax.pane.set_visible(False)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'pane'

Comment: If you could edit your question to have a minimal working example I will give it a go.

Comment: You can change the three axis panes with `ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color()`, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a black background it is easiest to set `matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('dark_background')`.

You can choose a style from `matplotlib.pyplot.style.available` and set your choice via `use`, e.g. `matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('ggplot')`.